# unable to run django project in other system

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project copied from a system. I have copied it to my system and I have put it in Apache www directory. Now When I run command

```
$python mamange.py runserver
```

it is giving error **Import Error: NO module named jet**

can anyone please identify bug. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made sure `jet` is installed? `pip install django-jet` (I think)

Comment: ok let me try that command

Comment: I run that command and now it gives import error : No module named rest_framework @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: have you tried my answer? If it didn't help, let me know and we can have a look in a chat quickly =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have all of your dependencies installed. If you have a `requirements.txt` (or similar) file run `pip install -r requirements.txt` (in the folder where the file is). Other wise you will need to install the requirements manually `pip install <list of requirements>`

Comment: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt

Comment: @InzmamulHassan Have you created the file?

Comment: no i haven't. and i have no idea where[in which directory] i have to create one?